# PersistenceUnit null with Glassfish and Quartz

Tags: jpa, glassfish-3, quartz-scheduler

I'm building a simple web app using jsp and servlets. The application is deployed on Glassfish server and use JPA / Hibernate.

I need to create a Quartz Job that work with JPA (select / update...). I've tried to add :

> ```
> @PersistenceUnit
> private EntityManagerFactory emf;
> ```

into my Job but it's null. By the way it works for my servlets and ServletContextListener.

I don't see how I can force glassfish to inject the persistence unit.

Any idea ?

THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injecting resources works only for container managed classes. Servlets and ServletContextListeners are container managed classes, your Quarz Job is not. Easiest way around is to use JNDI lookup.